# OpenGraph structured data listed as "Unspecified Type" in Google SDTT

Tags: google-rich-snippets, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

This is my first time working with structured data, so I'm not sure if this is even an issue, but when I run the Structured Data Testing Tool, I get 3 sets a data showing up like so:

[image]

Now `Article` and `WebSite` are correct, but at the top it says unspecified type. Now when I view that section I get this:

[image]

This seems to be loaded from all of my `og:tags`. I am specifying the type like so:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="WebSite"/>
```

but it’s still coming in as "Unspecified Type".

Is this correct? Is this something I need to worry about? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a problem that needs solving. The report in the SDTT is correct (there is no type specified), but that is expected when using the [OGP](http://ogp.me/) vocabulary.

Usually, a vocabulary has classes/types (like `Person`) and properties (like `name`), but OGP only has properties, which is somewhat unusual.

While OGP defines a `type` property, its value is just a string (like "website"), not an actual RDF class. In RDFa, classes would be specified within the `typeof` attribute.

A consumer specifically expecting the use of the OGP vocabulary will cope with this. Such a consumer might assume that OGP properties in a document are always about that document.

(Question about the same topic on Webmasters SE: [Tag property og:type not recognized by the Structured Data Tool](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/111514/17633); [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111522/17633) contains more details there.)